# Convert Minutes To hh:mm format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have time in minutes and I want to convert it into `hh:mm` format. Is this possible? When time exceeds after 24 hours it shows 00 at the beginning.

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(35), DATEADD(MINUTE, 1450, ''), 114)
```

Is it possible I display `25:34` or maybe `120:90` If hours exceeds `99` hours in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to calculate the hour & minute yourself. You can't convert time and then format using style 114

```
select  convert(varchar(10), 1450 / 60) + ':' + convert(varchar(10), 1450 % 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

All supported versions of SQL Server (2012 and later) provide the [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to format strings. The `format` string parameter works similar to .NET's format strings, which means you can use the same identifiers and create custom strings.

What it *doesn't* do, is work with multiple values, which is why each element has to be formatted separately :

```
declare @minutes int=1450

select format(@minutes/60,'#') + ':' + format(@minutes%60,'#')
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote! Care to explain why the function that formats strings shouldn't be used to ... format strings?